# How to Sort Rails Database Object in React Component

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, sorting

I have Objects in my Rails database that React is accessing for a Component.  React is displaying two of the attributes of those objects as a list.  I'd like to sort that list based upon one of the attributes that's not being displayed, but is available to React via the Rails database.  That attribute is the "updated_at" value.  Ideally, I'd like the most recently updated object to be displayed at the top of the list.

Data is available to React via this call:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
  const node = document.getElementById('projects_data') 
  const data = JSON.parse(node.getAttribute('data')) 
  ReactDOM.render( 
    <Projects projects={data} />, 
    destination) 
  })
```

Here's how I'm attempting to sort the list now with no success.  No errors, but it doesn't work.  Goal was to re-sort the list everytime a new object, called Project, was added to the database.

```
addNewProject(project){ 
    const projects = update(this.state.projects, { $push: [project]}); 
    this.setState({ 
        projects: projects.sort(function(a,b){ 
            return new Date(a['updated_at']) - new Date(b['updated_at']); 
        }) 
    }); 
}
```

Here's the List Component:

```
export const Project_list = ({projects}) =>  
    <table className="table">                   
      <tbody> 
        <tr> 
          <th>Project Name</th> 
          <th>Project Status</th> 
          <th>Action</th> 
        </tr> 
        {projects.map(function(project){         
           return (                         
             <Project project={project} key={project.id} />        
                  ) 
        })} 
      </tbody> 
    </table>
```

Comment: Can I introduce you to a great lib for tables with sorting, searching, .... http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/ I don't know what you want to do in the future, but I thought I save you from redefining the wheel :)

Comment: Are you sure you are returning the `updated_at ` for new added project?

Comment: @OzgurGUL I've added the object info to the question above, but the "updated_at" does appear in the object div for each object.

Comment: @Nocebo Thanks.  I'll check that library out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with two different fixes.

1. I added an "order" to my dashboard controller:

@projects = @current_user.projects.order("updated_at DESC")

2. I changed the "return new Date(a['updated_at']) - new Date(b['updated_at']); "
   to

   return new Date(b['updated_at']) - new Date(a['updated_at']);